# Mismatched table header border alignment causing duplicates while reading table using docx

Tags: python, parsing, ms-word, python-docx

I am reading a word file in python using docx. One of the table's border alignment is messed up. The top two rows (headers) have different alignment than the rest of the rows. As a result there are duplicate rows in the df in python. Below are screenshots of how the table looks like in word and VSCode:
[image]
[image] As you can see there are 11 columns instead of 6 (as in word).
I do not have control over how the file is created so feel like I only have the following options:

1. Change table border alignment of this table in python and save the docx file, then reopen it again
2. Clean up the duplicates and recreate the table

Second option is my preferred option, but its turning out to be a lot difficult than I thought.
Below is the code where I tried to fix the width of cells, save docx, and reopen it. But it does not work too well. The cells still have different widths so I am still getting duplicates.

> ```
> table  = doc.tables[6]
>
> from docx.shared import Cm, Inches
> cell_width = Inches(2)  
>
> table.autofit = False 
> table.allow_autofit = False
>
> for row in table.rows:
>     for cell in row.cells:
>         cell.width = cell_width
>
> doc.save('modified_document.docx')
> ```

[image]This is how the modified document looks like. As you can see the last column is still off in alignment.

Can add any other details if required. Would appreciate any help or any other ideas how to fix this. I have been stuck at this for a while.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This reflects a somewhat unfortunate consequence of the "user-friendly" table editing mechanism in Word. The short version is that each "mis-alignment" in the cell boundaries between rows is dealt with by Word by inserting an additional "layout-grid" column and then merging cells to make them look the way the author dragged and dropped them.

The layout-grid is the underlying rows and columns of the table. There is no "merging" in the layout grid. Every layout-grid row has the same number of columns.

Each visible cell in the table occupies one or more layout-grid cells. Occupying multiple is accomplished via merging. So in your example you have a lot of merged cells that aren't obvious.

In `python-docx`, accessing cells by row, like `for c in row.cells` gives you a Cell object for every *layout-grid column*. When a cell is merged horizontally (a "span"), the cell content appears in both (all) of these row-cells. This explains the repeated content. This works fine for simple and uniform tables, but unfortunately falls short once things get complicated or quirky, as in this case.

I believe the only option here is to "filter-out" the duplicates. Fixing the widths only works when editing the table manually in Word. `python-pptx` won't remove layout-grid columns that are no longer necessary.

The good news is that two layout-grid cells that are part of the same "merge" will compare equal (not only on their text, the actual object). So something like this is possible and reliable:

```py
def iter_unique_cells(cells):
    prior_cell = None
    for c in cells:
        if c == prior_cell:
            continue
        yield c
        prior_cell = c

unique_cells_for_this_row = list(iter_unique_cells(row.cells))
```

This of course can give you a different number of cells for different rows, so you have to work out which cell you're actually looking at based on knowledge of the tables you're working with, but maybe it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: This was great help, you are the GOAT! Thanks @scanny